# How do I stop File Explorer from running?

Tags: windows, batch-file

File Explorer lately has been getting very annoying. All the ads about OneDrive keep popping up. The ads are making me go crazy, I know how to access files using cmd, so I don't need File Explorer. How do I prevent File Explorer from running?

I've tried searching all over the internet, but all the results only show how to remove Quick Access or how to prevent File Explorer from running at startup. I want File Explorer to NEVER run again.

Comment: I'm scared of deleting explorer.exe, because I don't want to ruin my intstallation of Windows. When I search for explorer.exe there are multiple copies of it in different folders like in C:\Windows\WinSxS\explorer.exe.

Comment: This is not a programming problem. Your assertions are wrong anyway.

Comment: If the ads appear in Windows Explorer, and you don't ever need it, where's the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could instead try to simply disable the notifications you're having the issue with:

```bat
@Reg Add HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced /V ShowSyncProviderNotifications /T REG_DWORD /V 0 /F >NUL
```

Comment: Thanks for it! I never knew that!

Comment: @BrickMan, if this has solved your issue, you should consider marking it as accepted, by clicking on the large check mark to its left.

Comment: OK I did that! Again thanks for the advice!